# Bind IsEnabled to 2 sources

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I found this simple line of code to bind the IsEnabled property of a button to the presence/absence of a string inside a textbox:

```
<Button x:Name="startBtn" Content="Rinomina" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="255,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="36" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=seasonBox, Path=Text.Length}"/>
```

no C# code is needed. Now I would like to do the same things but with 2 textboxes instead one. I read about Multibinding but I can't figure out how to implement it. Can you help me, please? Is it possible using only xaml code?

Comment: Which part you don't understand. If you understand Binding and read about MultiBinding, it should be fairly straight forward. Please tell us where you are facing the problem.

Comment: All examples I have found use a converter in C# code, that's the part I can't understand. I wonder if there is a way to use Miltibindig using only XAML code for a situation easy like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to disable the `Button` when either of the `TextBoxes` are empty, you could use two triggers:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox1" />
<TextBox x:Name="textBox2" />

<Button x:Name="startBtn" Content="Rinomina" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="255,79,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="36">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=textBox1}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Text.Length, ElementName=textBox2}" Value="0">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Comment: Great, it works well. Many thanks. I'm wondering if my situation can be solved using Multibinding in XAML without a Converter in C#.

Comment: No, a MultiBinding is logical AND as opposed to logical OR. That's why you need to use two separate triggers.

Comment: I know Multibinding works as a logical AND. Your code achieve that using two trigger based on data textboxes. How I can do same thing using the Multibinding keyword?